# How to deselect the only <br> tag in regex?

Tags: regex

I tried to select without 
 but I am getting wrong output

Regex:

```
(&nbsp;|&quot;|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|<[^br].*>|\\W)
```

Input:

```
<br /> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<b>
</b>
<r>
</r>
<break>
<body>
<html>
<head>
```

Output:

```
Match 1
1.  &nbsp;
Match 2
1.  &nbsp;
Match 3
1.  </b>
Match 4
1.  </r>
Match 5
1.  <html>
Match 6
1.  <head>
Match 7
1.<break>

Match 8
1.<body>
```

Regex Link
http://rubular.com/r/hKtO4ojyye

Help Thanks..

Comment: Are you using Ruby? Try replacing `<[^br].*>` with `<(?!br(?:\s[^>]*)?>)[^>]+>`

Comment: This will match instances of `<br>` and `<br />`:  `(<br *\/?>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^br]` matches anything other than `b` or `r` so it won't match `b`.

Use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid matching `br`.

```
(&nbsp;|&quot;|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|<(?!br\\W).*?>|\\W)
```

Comment: Or more better `(?!br\\W)`

Comment: <break> custom tag not selected the above expression@Pranav C Balan